# What do you call this part for restricting/holding insecurely?

Tags: cable-management, terminology, fastening

Since I'm neither a professional repair-person, nor a native English speaker, I'm having a hard time figuring out what I would call this kind of a part:
[image]

(the thick frame is the surface the part is on, not the part itself.)

So, it is attached or fastened to a wider surface; it has one flat piece protruding from one end, and becoming parallel with the surface or even close to completing a loop - but not all the way. And it's supposed to be strong enough to withstand some weight, and if pulled on away from the surface - to spring back. So typically it would be metal (or thick plastic). It doesn't have to form a rectangle when projected onto the surface - its projection could be more eliptic or be a rectangle with half-discs at its top and bottom. Also, it might be mounted at a 90-degree angle to what I've described to prevent horizontal movement in one axis (or even both axes if it almost-closes its loop).

This is not quite a hanger, although it functions as one in a pinch; and it's not an eye-screw, although if opened up the eye of an eye screw it would serve reasonably well in this capacity. It's not a cable-rest device per se, although the functionality is related.

So what do you call such a part?

Comment: something like these? ... https://www.cwcyprus.com/_/cache/9dfb56b64dd4bc38b58bae09e894b245_w800_h600.jpg

Answer (score 3):

(One type of) **Cable clip** (there are other types that are called the same thing, but which are not open when installed, for instance.)

Here's an image (without endorsement) from a certain large internet store:

[image: Cable clip image from "Amazon"]

The "almost an eye hook" and thinking in terms of cable support also brings to mind **bridle rings** (which screw-clamp to beams, usually.) They can be had with or without the additonal yellow plastic bit shown. Here's an image (also without endorsement) from a smaller internet store. These are rigid, not springy, though you can bend them with a lot of force applied.

[image: Bridle ring cable support image from "Show Me Cables"]

It's also common to screw a piece of "hook and loop" fastener (the generic term for Velcro®) that's double-sided (hooks one side, loops the other) to the wall to make a support that can be fully closed around a cable, but which can also be opened if changes need to be made.